# Firebase SSR: lazy loaded routes not working

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an Angular 8 project with one lazy-loaded route. I have added Universal via the `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` command. Building and serving the app works fine.

I added firebase and set up SSR via a cloud function, partially following the guide on the [angularfire repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/universal/getting-started.md) which appears to be outdated.

Serving the app with `serve:ssr`, it works fine and requesting the lazy-loaded route works as well. But when testing with `firebase serve`, it only works until you request a lazy loaded route, (e.g., refresh page on lazy-loaded route) then an error is thrown:

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ssr-demo-b3ef3/us-central1/ssr'
>  Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ssr-demo-b3ef3/us-central1/ssr'
>      at router_ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (/Users/jamieperkins/Web-projects/GitHub/ngx-countup-with-ssr/functions/dist/webpack/server.js:149267:16)
>      at catchError_CatchSubscriber.urlTrees$.pipe.catchError [as selector] (/Users/jamieperkins/Web-projects/GitHub/ngx-countup-with-ssr/functions/dist/webpack/server.js:149231:28)
```

When deployed, the function crashes when the lazy-loaded route is requested.

The code is all on github in this repo (firebase branch): https://github.com/inorganik/ngx-countup-with-ssr/tree/firebase

To reproduce, clone the repo and do the following:

```
npm i
npm run build
npm run serve:ssr
```

should all work fine. But you try

```
firebase serve
```

and request the lazy-loaded route you'll get the error.

Angularfire issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2566).
firebase-tools issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1890).

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @RossRawlins angular 8 simply doesn't work with firebase SSR - best bet is to update to ng 11 or later and get the latest firebase packages. Use the schematics to generate all the code necessary

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you update your project to use the latest stable version of Angular and the @nguniversal/express-engine. get back to me if this solved your issue or that you for some reason are unable to update your project.

Comment: The repo above is what i used to reproduce an issue on a much larger project - I'm trying to hold off updating it for now. Plus I'm not convinced ng9/10 doesn't have the issue as well, because it seems to be rooted in firebase.

Comment: I believe the issue was fixed in Angular 9. Make a new branch and update, shouldn't hurt to try.